# Missing required parameters for [Route: homepage.edit] with link in layout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to `Laravel 5.4` and `php` and I'm having some trouble to do my routing, so I wish you would explain to me what's going on !

I'm developing a back office for my future projects, and for my current project I need to be able to update data sent to the homepage. The edit of the page and the update of the data is now fully functional, I'm just having some trouble to do the link in the layout. Pretty sure it's a trivial problem, yet i'm having trouble figuring it out.

Here is my code :

web.php :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin',  'middleware' => 'admin'], function()
{   
  Route::resource('homepage', 'Admin\HomeController');
});
```

HomeController :`

```
 public function edit($id) {
    $contentExists = Homepage::first();
    $homepage = Homepage::findOrFail($id);
    return view('admin/homepage/edit', compact('homepage', 'contentExists'));
}`
```

In the layout :

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
 <li>
  <a href="{{ route('homepage.edit') }}">Page d'accueil</a>
 </li>                          
</ul>
```

Now for that I know I need to pass a parameter to the route, so I did like so :

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
 <li>
  <a href="{{ route('homepage.edit', $homepage) }}">Page d'accueil</a>
 </li>                   
</ul>
```

But then it says the homepage variable is not defined, and I have no idea where I can define this variable since I'm in the layout, and also have no idea what needs to be inside this variable, what's his purpose... Can you help me with that ?

Comment: Well I think that the Homepage is not returning the variable because you are using Homepage::findorfail($id) so if it doesnt exist if will fail and not be passed to the view.

Comment: But that's in the HomeController, the variable passed on the link in in the layout the the homepage view, the controller does not handle this view

Comment: If you are just trying to get the link, instead of using `route('', '')` try and use `URL::route()` with the relevant parameters.

Comment: foudn another way to do it, though it's probably not the best ! Thank you for your help ^^

Answer (score 2):

route second parameter, must be an array like this for example:

```
route('homepage.edit', ['id' => 2])
```

Comment: I see better how it works ! How can I make it dynamic so I could do ['id' => $homepage->id] ?

Comment: found it, though i don't think this is the best way to do it, i opened the blade @php and defined the homepage variable equal to the datas gotten from the model and then called the id in the array ! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: in $homepage should be one result instead eloquent collection.You can try this command ['id' => $homepage->first()->id]